# Firebase Discord OIDC (Open ID)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, discord, openid-connect, openid

Been looking for a way to connect Discord Auth with Open ID
I have done all the steps according to the Firebase Open ID documentated found:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect?hl=en&authuser=0

I have found a similar Auth provider using OpenID to connect to Discord and they have a custom Issuer config as Discord does not provide a `.well-known/openid-configuration` per firebase documentation

Source: https://fusionauth.io/docs/lifecycle/authenticate-users/identity-providers/gaming/discord

The setup with Firebase OpenID is:

> Code Flow
>
> Discord
>
> Client ID from Discord App
>
> Issuer (URL): https://cdn.myproject.cloudflare.com/discord/  *see below
>
> Client ID from Discord App

In Discord Dev portal under OAuth2
The redirects has

> https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

*Issuer URL

https://cdn.myproject.cloudflare.com/discord/

points to public json data file named "openid-configuration" in a directory called ".well-known"

contents of issuer URL/.well-known/openid-configuration:

```js
{
    "issuer": "https://discord.com",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://discord.com/api/users/@me",
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "email",
        "profile"
    ]
}
```

this is enabled from my app with my other auth providers.
Do I need to use a URL Generator for the Issuer URL or something else?

The simple fact is that Firebase does not allow custom Issuer URL overrides.

processing the auth request with both redirect and popup:

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('oidc.discord');
//firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
        // IdP data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile.
        var credential = result.credential;
        var accessToken = credential.accessToken;
        var idToken = credential.idToken;
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

Error

```js
FirebaseError: Firebase: The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired. (auth/invalid-credential).
```

Alternative per suggested answers:
is to use OAuth2 within the browser by creating a custom Discord sign in link with `response_type=token` rather than `response_type=code`
which yields a url with a hash as follows:

```js
https://mycustomdomain.com/auth/redirect.html#token_type=Bearer&access_token=ty7QhLHdGNXnnHcnnR0eNIhALOf1w&expires_in=604800&scope=email
```

however this is only a decoded user profile and using:

```json
URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1)); const [accessToken, tokenType] = [fragment.get('access_token'), fragment.get('token_type')];
```

to process the data does not provide a valid custom token for Firebase Auth as this data is from Discord OAuth not from Firebase Auth Handler with OpenID

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(access_token)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        var user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('User', user)
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

Error:

```js
FirebaseError: Firebase: An internal AuthError has occurred. (auth/internal-error).
```

Comment: I made this feature request when OIDC was publicly released and no change has happened in the last 2 years.

Discord has said its a Firebase problem, and Firebase has said its a Discord problem

Answer (score -1):

how I achieved this was (flow)

1-> On redirect url get auth token
const fragment = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1));
const [accessToken, tokenType] = [fragment.get('access_token'), fragment.get('token_type')];

```
        if (!accessToken) {
            window.location.href('/')
        }
        fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
            headers: {
                authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
            },
        })
```

2-> after getting access token use firebase auth with custom token to signIn/Signup

Comment: this follows a simple validation process from Discord, an example found on Discord.js and has limitations without an intermediate server.
compare to the full auth grant flow: https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#authorization-code-grant-flow

Answer (score -1):

Use in on load event
const fragment = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1));
const [accessToken, tokenType] = [fragment.get('access_token'), fragment.get('token_type')];
then my previous code
and i am providing here a direction . solution is specific to every project.
follow documentation for step by step debug please

Comment: there must be something more to this as getting the actual access token from Discord via OAuth2 requires the discord app secret exposed and the token is not accepted by Firebase as its only ~30 characters long and does not represent a JWT.
and the getRedirectResult returns an error from Auth Handler reporting that the response is malformed. suggesting its incompatible.

Comment: You are using this on server? Right
It should be server side functions(can use firebase functions or a server)

Comment: No, this is for Firebase Auth with Open ID for front end authentication. My projects Auth is setup with Google Identity Toolkit to handle OpenID requests.

Comment: fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
                },
            }).then(result => result.json())
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    const { username, discriminator, avatar, id, email } = response;

like this its in js

Comment: This is not an answer for OpenID implementation. I am not interested in the old Cloud Functions OAuth2 method. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect